# Unexpected blank option in middle of select box

Tags: php, html, select

I am having a select option box which has four values pass, fail, hold and re-open. There is an unexpected blank option between fail and hold and I don't know why. Initially when I had only two options, I had this blank option.But now, when I have added other options this is in between and I want to remove it.

Here's the code:

```html
<?php
echo"<td><select  id='res[]' name='res[]' form='test'>";
echo"<option disabled selected value>--Result--</option>";
echo"<option value='Pass'>PASS</option>";
echo"<option value='Fail'>FAIL<option>";                     
echo"<option value='Hold'>HOLD</option>";
echo"<option value='Reopen'>RE-OPEN</option>";
echo"</select>";
echo "</td>"; 

?>
```

I am echoing this because this is to be done after a query. This is in a table and is present in all rows of it.
The current window:

[image: This is the select option currently:]
I dont want the blank option to appear! Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Note that this is inside a form and the values are posted to php

Edit: It's a typo by me! Got the solution. Forgot to close FAIL

Comment: Try echo '<option disabled selected value="">--Result--</option>';   maybe it needs a value?

Comment: You have not closed option in `Fail`. Should be `</option>` instead of `<option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to close the option tag properly. change your code to this

```
 echo"<td><select  id='res[]' name='res[]' form='test'>";
 echo"<option disabled selected value>--Result--</option>";
 echo"<option value='Pass'>PASS</option>";
 echo"<option value='Fail'>FAIL</option>";                     
 echo"<option value='Hold'>HOLD</option>";
 echo"<option value='Reopen'>RE-OPEN</option>";
 echo"</select>";
 echo"</td>";
```

**HTML Elements:**

An HTML element usually consists of a start tag and end tag, with the content inserted in between:

```
<tagname>Content goes here...</tagname>
```

The HTML element is everything from the start tag to the end tag.

Ex:    `<p>My first paragraph.</p>`

HTML elements with no content are called empty elements. Empty elements do not have an end tag, such as the `<br>` element (which indicates a line break). These are called *self-closing tags*. If we don't close this kind of tags, HTML closes it automatically

The other type of *Explicit Closing tag* which expects the closing tag.Some HTML elements will display correctly, even if you forget the end tag:

```
<p>This is a paragraph
<p>This is a paragraph
```

Never rely on this. It might produce unexpected results and/or errors if you forget the end tag.

Comment: OMG! Thanks! I was breaking my head for this from yesterday! Thank you so much! A small Typo!!

Comment: Yea it Happens sometimes...Try using this kind of editor  packages while coding https://atom.io/packages/autoclose-html

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
echo"<option value='Fail'>FAIL<option>";
```

To

```
echo "<option value='Fail'>FAIL</option>";
```

You forgot to close the `option` tag, it is creating a new one.

HTML is assuming that previous `option` tag is not closed and closes it automatically and creating a new blank option tag.

in HTML, there are two kinds of tags depending upon their closing.

**Self closing tags:**

`<input/>`

eg. `<input type="text" name="age"/>`

If we do not close this tag, HTML will close it automatically.

**Explicit closing tag:**

e.g.

`<textarea name="notes"></textarea>`

The `<option>` tag is of this type.

And it expects/assumes the closing tag.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Pupil !! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the mistake in your html

```
echo"<option value='Fail'>FAIL<option>";
```

it should be like this

```
 echo"<option value='Fail'>FAIL</option>";
```